# Fill up column based on condition goes wrong

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to fill a column based on condition but something goes wrong.

So I am expecting if it is not 2017 there should be a no.

But yet the years 2019 and 2020 also get filled up with yes.

Does anyone know what went wrong?

```
``
dfV['is_vacation'] = np.where((dfV['year'] == 2017) & 
                             (dfV['week_nr'] ==  26) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  27) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  28)
                              & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  29) & (dfV['week_nr'] == 30) &
                              (dfV['week_nr'] ==  31) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  32) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  33) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  34)
                              & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  35) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  42) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  43) & (dfV['week_nr'] ==  44), 'Yes', 'No')
``
``
```

Comment: Did you mean `(dfV['week_nr'] ==  26) | (dfV['week_nr'] ==  27) | ...` (i.e., bitwise *or* instead of *and*)? Because a cell cannot simultaneously be equal to 27 and 28, the condition will never be `True`. Better yet, I'd recommend you use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and/or [`.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) instead `&` for bitwise `AND`, for chain by bitwise `OR` use `|`:

```
dfV = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2017,2018,2019,2017,2017,2017], 
                    'week_nr':[43,30,20,40,30,36]})

dfV['is_vacation'] = np.where((dfV['year'] == 2017) & 
                               (dfV['week_nr'].between(26, 35) | 
                                dfV['week_nr'].between(42, 44)), 
                               'Yes', 'No')
print (dfV)
   year  week_nr is_vacation
0  2017       43         Yes
1  2018       30          No
2  2019       20          No
3  2017       40          No
4  2017       30         Yes
5  2017       36          No
```

Or:

```
L = list(range(26, 36)) + list(range(42, 45))

dfV['is_vacation'] = np.where((dfV['year'] == 2017) & dfV['week_nr'].isin(L), 
                              'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: Yes, but it looks like OP wants to exclude 36..41.

Comment: I will try that.. but I do not want week 39 for example to count as a vacation week

Comment: @afbz - So need `Yes` if year==2017 and not `between(26, 44)` ?

Comment: @afzb - Add sample data to answer.

Comment: Eventually I will need something like if year is 2017 and week numbers are between 26 and 35 and weeknumbers are between 41 and 42. than it must be true/yes the same goes for the year 2019 and 2020 but I started with 2017 to practice with ofcourse the weeknumbers in 2019 and 2020 are slightly diferent

Comment: @afzb - Answer was edited.